# Unity Networking | ClientRpc being called on the wrong player object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

The Problem: My `RpcDie` method is being called on the wrong GameObject.

I.e: When Player A kills Player B, it is Player A who dies - not Player B.

But this is only locally. So the behavior above only happens on Player A's game, and on Player B's game everything seems to be happening as expected. The opposite is also true.

So: Player A kills player B. From Player A's perspective they are dead and Player B is alive. From Player B's perspective, they have died and Player A is alive.

---

In the `Update` method of my `PlayerHealth` script I check to see if the players hp is less than 1. If it is, then I call the `CmdDie` method:

```
if (playerHealth < 1)
     CmdDie();
```

From `CmdDie` I call my `RpcDie` method:

```
// Calls RpcDie
[Command]
public void CmdDie ()
{
    RpcDie(); 
}

// Removes the player from the game when killed by another player
[ClientRpc]
void RpcDie ()
{
    // Checks
    if (!isLocalPlayer || PlayerUnit.isDead) return;

    // Toggles + updates     
    StopAllCoroutines(); 
    GameObject.Find("MapManager").GetComponent<GameManager>().playerCount--;
    GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    PlayerUnit.isDead = true; 

    // Ragdoll
    ragdoll.SetActive(true); 
    foreach (Transform t in ragdoll.transform) 
       t.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position;
}
```

From debugging I know that the player's health is being subtracted on the correct GameObject. It is only when a player dies that this 'switching' occurs.

Comment: Is `PlayerUnit.isDead` a static? Does this maybe influence both players? How do you differ between `A` and `B`? maybe naming is mixed up on the client side?

Comment: @derHugo `PlayerUnit.isDead` is static, but removing it doesn't change anything. If naming is mixed up on the client-side, I'm not sure how it's happening because even if I remove the `[Command]` and `[ClientRpc]` attributes (i.e. make them normal methods, exactly the same way I've done my player movement) nothing changes. Also, while running the client and host side by side - I noticed that on Player A's screen Player A dies when they kill Player B. But its the opposite on Player B's screen. I've added this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

From my assumptions, `playerHealth` is not stating "who" the player actually is; whether if its `Player A` or `Player B`. The script does not know that health should be reduced for `Player B`, rather than `Player A`.

Each player would have a `PlayerID`; hence, `Player A` would have `PlayerID: 1`, and `Player B` would have `PlayerID: 2`.

A more technical scenario would be the Client to Server communication.
When `Player A` would want to attack `Player B`, the client (which is `Player A`) would send an `RPC` request to the server that he want to attack `Player B`.

The server would receive a "Packet" containing the information sent from the `RPC`, including: `PlayerID` which is initiating the attack (in this case it is `PlayerID: 1` (A)), and the other `PlayerID` who has been attacked (`PlayerID: 2`). There would be more information in the packet for instance the `WeaponID`, and so on.

Lastly, the server would send another `RPC` to everyone which pseudo code would be something like `ReducePlayerHealth(int playerID, int healthAmount, RPC.NotifyAll)`

That method would send each and every player in the game a packet in which the client would reduce the health of that specific player. The server must always be in command; therefore, the server sets the data, and the client reads the data.

P.S: Had to post it as an answer since I could not input more characters under the comment section of your question.

Comment: just a sidenote but afaik player IDs are usually `0` based

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. How would I tell `PlayerHealth` who the player is? I understand how networking works on the level you describe, but I am confused because my player movement works in practically the same way as my `PlayerHealth` script except, well, that works fine.